# Advice for collecting and storing ASP.NET Performance Counters?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure, performance, iis

We haven't had any experience on Windows Performance Counters so have been researching them. Can anyone see any flaws in the following plan to monitor ASP.NET performance for a website?

We have IIS running on an Azure Virtual Machine for one ASP.NET website with an Azure SQL Database.

- Use a cron job to call \get-performance-counters\default.aspx every 5 minutes
- In default.aspx.vb, have code to get all Performance Counters and their values for the ASP.NET Category and the SQL Server Category
- Store those Performance Counter names and values, and a time stamp in a SQL database table
- Have a webpage to vertically display a list of all Performance Counter Names with 12 value columns: 0 minutes ago, 5 minutes ago, 10 minutes ago, 15 minutes ago etc, 60
  minutes ago.
- Note I did read that it's best to call a performance counter, thread sleep for 5 seconds then call it again. I'm not sure if this applies to all counters though.